# Java Rounding (Double)

Tags: java, double, rounding

```
double y1 = 0;  
double y2 = 0;  
double i = 0.025;  
double n = 2;  
double h1 = 2000; 
double h2 = 4000; 

y1 = Math.pow((1 + i), n) * h1;
y2 = Math.pow((1 + i), n) * h2;
double result =  y1 + y2;
System.out.println(result);
```

I want the result as "6303.749999999999" but it gives me "6303.75". How can i solve it?

Comment: You _want_ `6303.749999999999`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: Isn't that the same as wanting 0.999999999999 with code like: double a = 1?

Comment: why  would you even **want** to print an incorrect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct result should be (and it is)
6303.750000000000017069679003611781820568916563219777423023367655509563911228609889292329171439632773399353027343750000

Try to give a look at the BigDecimal class.

```
    BigDecimal i = new BigDecimal(0.025);
    int n = 2;
    BigDecimal h1 = new BigDecimal(2000);
    BigDecimal h2 = new BigDecimal(4000);

    BigDecimal y1 = ((BigDecimal.ONE.add(i)).pow(n)).multiply(h1);
    BigDecimal y2 = ((BigDecimal.ONE.add(i)).pow(n)).multiply(h2);
    BigDecimal result =  y1.add(y2);

    System.out.println(result.toEngineeringString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are *calculating* the value `6303.75`. if you add a statement where you subtract the value `0.000000000001` from the variable `result` then you will get the expected value `6303.749999999999`.

The below code changes demonstrate how you can instead calculate `6303.749999999999`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    double y1 = 0;  
    double y2 = 0;  
    double i = 0.025;  
    double n = 2;  
    double h1 = 2000; 
    double h2 = 4000; 

    y1 = Math.pow((1 + i), n) * h1;
    y2 = Math.pow((1 + i), n) * h2;
    double result =  y1 + y2;
    result -= (double)0.000000000001; // this line is the key to calculating the expected result
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**Output:**

> 6303.749999999999